# Проблемы с ListView, передача последнего ID пункта

Tags: java, android, listview

Всем доброго времени суток, есть AsyncTask:

```
...

static String endMsg_id;

...

class MessageLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            return Function.postChatUrl(params[0], endMsg_id);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
    }
}
```

В **postChatUrl(params[0], fr_id)** нужно передать мне ID последнего сообщения который находится в ListView.

Адаптер:

```
class ChatAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Добраться до нужного мне ID, Пробовал так:

```
sList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvChat);
            for(int i = 0; i < sList.getCount(); i++) {
                if(i == sList.getCount() - 1) {
                    TextView msgID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msg_id);
                    endMsg_id = msgID.getText().toString();
                    Log.d(LOG_CAT, "Последнее сообщение: " + endMsg_id);
                }
            }
```

И вроде бы всё хорошо, но...
Допустим самый последний элемент имеет **ID 15** - который мне нужно отправить, теперь, если активити загружена, и я быстро (до обновления хандлера) прокручу не много список, то самый последний элемент отправляется уже не как **ID 15**, а **ID 12**. Я так понимаю отправляется **текущий видимый** на экране элемент. Как мне это обойти так, что бы я мог знать ID последнего элемента не зависимо от положения ListView? Если можно примерчик, за ранее благодарю..

А вообще суть вопроса в том что бы подгружать сообщения с сервера только в том случае, если в БД, id последнего сообщения у конкретного юзера, изменился. Хочу реализовать это для того что бы постоянно не загружать данные в адаптер, и не обновлять его до тех пор, пока не произойдут изменения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так получится:

```
int lastItem = lv.getAdapter().getCount();
```

...

```
String lastName = lv.getItemAtPosition(lastItem -1).toString();
```

Comment: В моём случае `int lastItem`, идентичен `sList.getCount()...`Как произвести саму выборку? Допустим `выбрать lastItem и у этого lastItem, выбрать определённый TextView..и сформировать текст в виде getText().toString`

Comment: Ясно, сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Спасибо) Ожидаю..

Comment: Я вместо тоста написал, выведет текст последнего элемента в списке. Вроде то , что Вам нужно

Comment: А теперь `String lastName` нужно преобразовать в массив? Сейчас результат таков: `{msg_id=50, us_id=1, textChat=sdf, text=Сергей}`

Comment: Shwarz Andrei, спасибо вам огромное, помогли мне очень. Оставшееся доделал так: `int lastItem = sList.getAdapter().getCount();
            String lastID = sList.getItemAtPosition(lastItem - 1).toString();
            String[] spl = lastID.split("[,=\\s]+");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "lastItem:: - " + spl[1]); - 50 <- то что нужно`